# How to show codecept_debug messages when debugging project unit tests in PhpStorm?

Tags: unit-testing, phpstorm, codeception

When running unit tests thru *PhpStorm*, the output of function `codecept_debug` is ignored.

I've set my *Test runner options* to:

```
--colors --debug -v
```

In my `codeception.yml` I also have:

```
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    debug: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
```

On command line the output of `codecept_debug` **is displayed**.

Comment: Last time I checked, it couldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not implemented yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36233. Please vote/comment for the issue

Comment: Not the answer I expected:) Hopefully they will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is still unsupported by PHPStorm however you can work around this by:

- changing your `codecept_debug( $variable )` calls to `echo print_r( $variable, true );`

In the same way you will do it with `codecept_debug` the output should be displayed on the terminal of PHPStorm when running the tests.